# Log input traffic using iptables

Tags: iptables, logfiles

Is it possible to log input traffic coming to wired Ethernet port using iptables, without syslog running? I want to know about appearance of particular MAC address WiFi node in range of my home WiFi network (does not matter TCP or UDP). Moreover, I want to log it to another file located on SSD HDD connected to USB port.
I try to use such statement:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m mac --mac-source 90:b6:86:38:46:fa -j LOG --log-prefix "Note4"
```

But nothing was logged. I dont want to run (r)syslog because of lifespan of SD card. I dont want to use tcpdump too because it is "to heavy" for my needs and I dont want to inspect each packet. But I just want to know about the appearance of particular node in my network. Just kind of geofencing
Any idea?

Comment: This question is not specific to Raspberry Pi. It's general about iptables. You should better ask at https://superuser.com

Comment: From my point of view it is typical RPi problem of implementation iptables in RPi environment (SD card, no syslog running etc).